# Correct way to expose ingress service using baremetal Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have the following topology in my kubernetes cluster:

[image]

So, I have 2 Nodes: 1 Master and 1 Worker Node.

[image]

Now I created an application with my deployment.yml and my service.yml, using nodePort configuration, see:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: administrativo-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: administrativo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

And this is my service:

[image]

Now I need to access this API using my DNS, something like: myapi.localdns, so I followed this steps to install Ingress Controller based on nginx:

- https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start
- https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#bare-metal-clusters

After 1 hour this is POD status in ingress-nginx namespace:

[image]

And finally, this is my Ingress yml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: administrativo-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myapi.localdns
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: administrativo-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Well, my idea is to create an entry in my company to DNS to point to this DNS **myapi.localdns**:

[image]

but to do it I need the Ingress Address, that don't show in my ingress resource, see:

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify the problem (in one specific sentence)? What exactly do you want to achive? What did you try? Could you provide deployment.yml? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: I want to expose my application through ingress but didn't work. In my post a give details about it, like the fact that I'm using bare metal installation

Comment: Could you provide your logs?

Comment: I posted the solution

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, using this steps:

1. First create in my company DNS the CNAMEs pointing to my kubernetes workernode IP.
2. Reinstall ingress-nginx controller using bare-metal configuration: kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.0.5/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml.
3. Change the deploy.yaml to use NodePort before use `kubectl apply`
4. Use `externalIPS` to expose my service in port 80.